# OpenGL Plane not showing up

Tags: opengl, glut

I'm making a particle fountain in openGL, I have the particles functioning properly. I decided to add a plane to make it look like they are bouncing off from it. What I'm trying to get is something like this
[image]

Unfortunately what I'm getting is this

[image]

the plain doesn't seem to be appearing at all. I tried messing with the co-ordinates and that doesn't seem to do anything. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEJR0.png) is the image I'm using as the texture, it's a 256 X 256 24bit bmp.

I load the texture in the init function, then call it before I render the particles in the following function

```
void Load_Plane(){
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL_SRC_ALPHA);
    glColor4f(0.0f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.5f);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, txPlane);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glNormal3f(-10.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(-10.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f( 10.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f( 10.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-10.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f);
    glEnd();
}
```

full code

```
// particle_fountain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<Windows.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <GL\glut.h>
#include<GL\GLU.h>

#define MAX_PARTICLES 200 //max number of particles
#define MAX_BOUNCE_COUNT 5 //number of times a particle should bounce 
#define MAX_PARTICLE_AGE 95

//Colours
float R = 0.8f;
float G = 0.2f;
float B = 0.0f;
float cR = 0.001f;
float cG = 0.002f;
float cB = 0.003f;
float Size = 0.02f; //size for points
GLuint txParticle;
GLuint txPlane;


struct PARTICLE {
    float X,Y,Z; // Current position
    float sX,sY,sZ; // Current Speed/Movement
    float tX,tY,tZ; // Target Speed/Movement
    float R,B,G; // Particle Colour
    bool Active; // Is particle Active
    int Age; // Age of the particle
    int MaxAge; // Maximum Age before particle dies
    int BounceCount;
} Particles[MAX_PARTICLES];

void Init_Particles();
void Activate_Particles();
void Adjust_Particles();
void Render_Particles();
bool LoadBitmapTexture(char * FileName, GLuint &texid);
void timer(int extra);
void Load_Plane();
void DrawGLscene();
void Reshape(GLsizei w, GLsizei h);

int main(int argc, char** argv){
     glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA| GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutInitWindowSize( 640, 480 );    
    glutCreateWindow("Particle fountain");

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glFrustum(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 10.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.0, -0.9, -3.0); 


    Init_Particles();
    glutDisplayFunc(DrawGLscene);
    glutTimerFunc(0, timer, 0);
    glutMainLoop();

}

void timer(int extra)
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(20, timer, 0);
}

void Load_Plane(){
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL_SRC_ALPHA);
    glColor4f(0.0f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.5f);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, txPlane);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glNormal3f(-10.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(-10.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f( 10.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f( 10.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-10.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f);
    glEnd();
}
void DrawGLscene(){
    Load_Plane();
    glPushMatrix();
    glScalef(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    Render_Particles();
    glPopMatrix();
    Render_Particles();

}


void Init_Particles(){
    LoadBitmapTexture("./Particle.bmp", txParticle); //load the particle texture 
    LoadBitmapTexture("./Plain.bmp",txPlane); //load the plain texture

    int p;
    srand((int)time(NULL));
    for(p=0; p<MAX_PARTICLES; p++){
        Particles[p].Active = FALSE;
        Particles[p].tX = 0.0f;
        Particles[p].tY = -0.1f;
        Particles[p].tZ = 0.0f;
    }
}

void Activate_Particles(){
    int p;
    for(p=0; p<MAX_PARTICLES; p++){
        if(!Particles[p].Active){
            // Start the particle at 0,0,0 origin
            Particles[p].X = 0.0f;
            Particles[p].Y = 0.0f;
            Particles[p].Z = 0.0f;
            // The following lines set a random speed value
            Particles[p].sX = (((float)((rand() % 100) + 1)) /
                1000.0f) - 0.05f;
            Particles[p].sY = (((float)((rand() % 100) + 50)) /
                500.0f);
            Particles[p].sZ = (((float)((rand() % 100) + 1)) /
                1000.0f) - 0.05f;
            // We also activate the particle
            Particles[p].Active = true;
            // Set it's Age to zero
            Particles[p].Age = 0;
            // We also assign a max age to the particles
            Particles[p].MaxAge = MAX_PARTICLE_AGE;
            // We Also reset the bouncecount to zero
            Particles[p].BounceCount = 0;

            //Adding the colours
            Particles[p].R = R;
            Particles[p].G = G;
            Particles[p].B = B;
            R+=cR;
            G+=cG;
            B+=cB;
            if(R>1.0f){R=1.0f; cR=-cR;}
            if(R<0.0f){R=0.0f; cR=-cR;}
            if(G>1.0f){G=1.0f; cG=-cG;}
            if(G<0.0f){G=0.0f; cG=-cG;}
            if(B>1.0f){B=1.0f; cB=-cB;}
            if(B<0.0f){B=0.0f; cB=-cB;}
            return;
        }
}
}

void Adjust_Particles(){
    int p;
    for(p=0; p<MAX_PARTICLES; p++){
        // We move the speed towards the target speed by 1/20 (5%)
        Particles[p].sX+= (Particles[p].tX - Particles[p].sX) / 20.0f;
        Particles[p].sY+= (Particles[p].tY - Particles[p].sY) / 20.0f;
        Particles[p].sZ+= (Particles[p].tZ - Particles[p].sZ) / 20.0f;
        // Then we adjust the position of
        // the particle by the new speed
        Particles[p].X+= Particles[p].sX;
        Particles[p].Y+= Particles[p].sY;
        Particles[p].Z+= Particles[p].sZ;
        // Now for the bounce code.
        if(Particles[p].Y < 0.0f){
            Particles[p].Y = 0.0f;
            Particles[p].sY = -Particles[p].sY;
            Particles[p].BounceCount++;
            if(Particles[p].BounceCount > MAX_BOUNCE_COUNT){
                Particles[p].Active = FALSE;
            }
        }
        // And finally the age check
        Particles[p].Age++;
        if(Particles[p].Age > Particles[p].MaxAge){
            Particles[p].Active = FALSE;
        }
    }

}

void Render_Particles(){
    Activate_Particles();
    Adjust_Particles();

    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    int p;
    // Enable textures and bind our particle texture
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, txParticle);
    // Disable Depth testing.
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    // Enable blending
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_COLOR,GL_ONE);
    for(p=0; p<MAX_PARTICLES; p++){
        if(Particles[p].Active){
            glColor4f(Particles[p].R,
                Particles[p].G,
                Particles[p].B, 1.0f);
            glPushMatrix();
            glTranslatef(Particles[p].X,
                Particles[p].Y,
                Particles[p].Z);
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
            glVertex3f(-Size, -Size, 0.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
            glVertex3f(Size, -Size, 0.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
            glVertex3f(Size, Size, 0.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
            glVertex3f(-Size, Size, 0.0f);
            glEnd();
            glPopMatrix();


        }
    }
     glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
     glutSwapBuffers();
}

bool LoadBitmapTexture(char * FileName, GLuint &texid){
    HBITMAP hBMP; // Handle Of The Bitmap
    BITMAP BMP; // Bitmap Structure
    glGenTextures(1, &texid); // Create The Texture
    hBMP=(HBITMAP)LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL),
        FileName,
        IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0,
        LR_CREATEDIBSECTION | LR_LOADFROMFILE
        );

    if (!hBMP) // Does The Bitmap Exist?
        return FALSE; // If Not Return False
    GetObject(hBMP, sizeof(BMP), &BMP); // Get The Object
    // hBMP: Handle To Graphics Object
    // sizeof(BMP): Size Of Buffer For Object Information
    // &BMP: Buffer For Object Information
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);
    // Pixel Storage Mode (Word Alignment / 4 Bytes)
    // Typical Texture Generation Using Data From The Bitmap
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texid);// Bind To The Texture ID
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
        GL_LINEAR); // Linear Min Filter
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
        GL_LINEAR); // Linear Mag Filter
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, BMP.bmWidth, BMP.bmHeight,
        0, GL_BGR_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, BMP.bmBits);
    DeleteObject(hBMP); // Delete The Object
    return TRUE; // Loading Was Successful
}
```

Comment: Have you tried error check with `glGetError`?

Comment: What is `BMP.bmBitsPixel` for your image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that you're not clearing the depth buffer.

It doesn't affect any of the particles because you are disabling depth test when you render them, but when you render the plane, depth test is enabled, and since the depth buffer has not been cleared it has a spaz and doesn't render the plane.

Do

```
glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

before you render the plane to clear the depth buffer.

EDIT:
This must be it-

You are calling

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

*after* you render the plane. Look at your DrawGLScene function:

```
Load_Plane(); // you are drawing the plane here
glPushMatrix();
glScalef(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
Render_Particles(); // this function calls "glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );"
// so anything that you rendered before is now removed.
glPopMatrix();
Render_Particles(); // same goes for here.
```

The solution would be to remove the call to glClear from your Render_Particles function,
and add it to the top of DrawGLScene:

(New DrawGLScene Code)

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
Load_Plane();
glPushMatrix();
glScalef(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
Render_Particles();
glPopMatrix();
Render_Particles();
```

EDIT #2:

You're calling glutSwapBuffers in the Render_Particles function.
Don't call it there. Call it at the end of DrawGLScene:

Comment: I added `glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);` before calling the Load_Plain() function, unfortunately that didn't fix the issue.

Comment: @cyberbemon I think I have it! Reread my answer, I edited it and put in the new possible solution!!

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't make it work, I even changed the texture, still no use !

Comment: @cyberbemon Once again I noticed another thing, edited, check my answer.

Comment: @ ForgiveMeI'mAN00b sorry bro, but that didn't fix it, I'm starting to think the texture might be messed up, or this program hates me !

Comment: @cyberbemon well that's all I can help you with then good luck!